# Duplicate MAC address in VMware deploying from template

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter, mac-address

I am trying to deploy a VM from a template. This template has been used dozens of times before; nothing special. The problem is that seemingly out of nowhere when I deploy a VM, it's giving it the same MAC address as an existing powered on VM.

Both VMs are using automatic MAC assignment.

It seems that the usual cause for this is [having more than 1 vCenter without giving each one a unique ID](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1024025). Thing is, we only have 1 vCenter.

I have confirmed in the vCenter database, using the following query, that there are no other conflicts in the cluster:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1000 
      [MAC_ADDRESS],
      COUNT([MAC_ADDRESS])
  FROM [VIM_VCDB].[dbo].[VPX_NIC]
  GROUP BY MAC_ADDRESS
  HAVING COUNT([MAC_ADDRESS]) > 1
```

I keep deleting the newly minted VM and trying to re-deploy it, but it gives out the same MAC every time.

When I create a new VM from scratch, it uses a unique MAC.

I can't find any other instances of something like this online, and I can't figure out how this is possible nor what I can do to fix it. I don't want to start assigning MAC addresses manually.

### Update

This has gone from a problem that was repeatable to.. not a problem. I don't know what happened or why, but this originally occurred for me on Friday evening, several times. I was able to repeat it this morning before posting this.

Testing now shows unique MACs being generated; no duplicates.

I have no idea why, I'd still like insight if anyone has ideas. I have  a sneaking suspicion that this is going to come back. Ugggh.

Comment: You're using the full templating feature to deploy the VM, rather than cloning it or something aren't you? And are there are no 3rd party tools?

Comment: It is an actual template being deployed, with a customization profile. The new VM has nothing to do with the existing one except that they were from the same template originally. I converted the template back to a VM to see if its NIC had the same MAC as these 2 are getting, but it's different. No 3rd party tools are being used for this deployment. I am using a [script to generate IP addresses](http://kb.vmware.com/kb/2007557), but this script receives the MAC address from VMware, so it has no part in generating it.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen similar issues after upgrading vCenter with old customization profiles, after some version upgrades the profiles become flaky. The usual fix is to just recreate the customization profile from scratch.